# Is there a proof that the distance from $0$ to $i$ in the complex plane is $1$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I was just wondering how did people know that the distance between $0$ and $i$ is $1$ in the complex plane, did they just assume this, is it just an axiom, or is there a proof behind it or a reason for it?

Comment: I suppose it's just a convention to put $i$ at a distance $1$ from the origin in the complex plane; but it's nice to have $|zw|=|z||w|$ where $|z|$ denotes the distance from $z$ to the origin, don't you think?

Comment: In some sense, I think the ordinate of a point $z$ at complex plane is exactly its imaginary part, by definition $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $z=a+bi$ ($a\in\mathbb{R}$ as well). I understand the answers below, by in some sense I thinks it's a definition (maybe some answer are ciclic). I'd like to receive answer to this comment... I'm curious now. Thanks.

Comment: How did people know that the distance between $0$ and $1$ is $1$ in the complex plane? Same thing.

Comment: How did we know that the distance from $(0,1)$ to $(0,0)$ = $1$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I think that is the heart of it. As a real vector space the complex numbers can be regarded as an affine system, and one can create a metric using any pair of basis vectors as units. But if you want the metric to be compatible with multiplication of complex numbers then there is only one choice.

Answer (score 3):

We define the distance between $x$ and $y$ in the complex plane as being $||x-y||$ where if $||a+bi||^2 = a^2+b^2$. Substitution gives that the distance between $i$ and $0$ is $||i-0||=||i||=1^2=1$. However, this doesn't really explain why this is true. However, if you are familiar with vectors the formula $||x-y||$ should look familiar. In fact, this is just the same distance formula we use in the plane. So what happened is that we decided that the distance between $a+bi$ and $c+di$ should be the same as the distance between $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$. In some sense, this is the more fundamental assumption about what we mean by distance in the complex plane, and then the fact that the distance from $0$ to $i$ is $1$ follows from that.

Comment: The first four words cannot be overemphasized

Comment: so there isn't really a proof? just an axiom?

Comment: @MohannadEl-Nesr. There is no proof of the definition, but given the definition, there is the proof outlined above (ie. the distance between $i$ and $0$ is $||i||=1^2=1$)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $i=(0,1)$ and the origin is $(0,0)$

According to the distance formula we get $d= \sqrt {0^2+1^2} =1$

Comment: +1 What are we missing? This seems trivial. We knew because we defined the complex numbers.

Comment: @JohnDouma exactly, it's "defined" but I am searching for a proof, obviously it's just convention from the answers I've been seeing but really stating the distance formula doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

This is, as mentioned by others, a matter of definition, but there is a reason to believe that the definition is correct.

Given a real polynomial $p(x)=(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_n)$ with the $a_i$ real, then, when $a$ is a real number such that $p(a)\neq 0,$ the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $1/p(x)$ at $x=a$ is $\min_i |a-a_i|.$

We can also show[*] that the Taylor series for the real function  $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$ at $x=a$ has interval of convergence with radius equal to $\sqrt{1+a^2}.$

This gives the impression that, if there there are roots of $x^2+1,$ they must be a distance $1$ from $0$ in a direction perpendicular to the real line.

So, even before we have the complex numbers, we know roughly “where” we’d want the root(s) to $x^2+1$ to exist, if they exist.

---

[*] It is a tedious argument if kept in the reals, but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The distance between two complex numbers $z$ and $z'$ is the module of the difference $|z-z'|$. In particular, the distance to $0$ is the module.

Now $|z|^2=z\bar z$, so $|i|^2=i(-i)=1$, hence $|i|=\sqrt 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{C}=\{x+iy:x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ where $i$ is a root of the equation $z^2+1=0$. A metric $d:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is defined by $d((x_1+iy_1),(x_2+iy_2))=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$ for $x_j,y_j\in\mathbb{R},j=1,2.$ This metric is called the natural distance in $\mathbb{C}$ because of its similarity with the distance in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ Now by this definition, distance between $0$ and $i$ is $d((0+0i),(0+1i))=\sqrt{0+1}=1.$

Comment: Thanks! That was a typo. Edited now.

Comment: You also have $x_2$ and $y_1$ swapped.

Answer (score 0):

We simply have by definition

$$|i|=\sqrt{1^2}=1$$

[image]

(credit Wikipedia)